# Why is redux toolkit not returning state?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a reducer that supposed to return the the orders json object with is_confirmed set to 1.  For some reason the code below doesn't return any state at all. The orders state disappears. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
  confirmOrder : (state, action)=> {

         const payload = action.payload;
         const selected_order_id =payload.selected_order_id;
         //console.log(payload.selected_order_id,"id");

      return  state.orders.map((order)=>{
          //  console.log(order);

            if(selected_order_id === order.id){
                return {...order,is_confirmed : 1}

            } else {
                //console.log(state);
                return state;
            }
        })
         
     }
```

here is the full code below

```
const initalState = {orders : []}

const orders = createSlice({
    name : "orders",
    initialState : initalState,
    reducers : {
         addToOrders : (state, action)=> {
             return {
                 ...state,orders : state.orders.concat(action.payload)
             }
         },

         confirmOrder : (state, action)=> {

             const payload = action.payload;
             const selected_order_id =payload.selected_order_id;
             //console.log(payload.selected_order_id,"id");

          return  state.orders.map((order)=>{
              //  console.log(order);

                if(selected_order_id === order.id){
                    return {...order,is_confirmed : 1}

                } else {
                    //console.log(state);
                    return state;
                }
            })

         }
    }

})

export const {addToOrders,confirmOrder} = orders.actions;
export  default  orders.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

confirmOrder : (state, action)=> {

```
     const payload = action.payload;
     const selected_order_id =payload.selected_order_id;
     //console.log(payload.selected_order_id,"id");

  return  state.orders.map((order)=>{
      //  console.log(order);

        if(selected_order_id === order.id){
            return {...order,is_confirmed : 1}

        } else {
            //console.log(state);
            return state;
        }
    })
     
 }
```